# RMONGODB: Aggregation fails with error "mongoDB error: 10" while working on large datasets

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection F with 6+ million documents. This collection has the following structure

```
         { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5718277b3f33da6dfaeaec88"), 
            "f_id" : "F1", 
            "f_date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "effectiveTimeStamp" : ISODate("2016-11-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "level1" : [
                {
                    "sequence" : "1", 
                    "level2"   : [
                    {"c_Code" : "TR",
                     "level3" : [{ "flevel_total" : 51
                                  }
                                ]
                    }
                    ]
                }
            ]
         }
```

I need to deconstruct a couple of array fields from these documents for further processing.

```
   minfdate <-as.POSIXct('2016-12-01', tz = "GMT") 
   maxfdate <- as.POSIXct('2017-01-10', tz = "GMT")

   coll_name = 'test.F'

cmd_list = list(
  mongo.bson.from.list(list("$match" = 
                              list( "$and" = list(list("Date" = list("$gte" = as.POSIXct(minfdate, tz = "GMT"))),list("Date" = list("$lte" = as.POSIXct(maxfdate, tz = "GMT")))))
  )),
mongo.bson.from.JSON('{"$unwind": "$level1"}'),
mongo.bson.from.JSON('{"$unwind": "$level1.level2"}'),
mongo.bson.from.JSON('{"$unwind": "$level1.level2.level3"}'),
mongo.bson.from.JSON('{"$project": {
                     "f_Id":            "$f_Id", 
                     "f_Date": "$Date",
                     "sequence":            "$level1.sequence",
                     "effectiveTimeStamp" : "$effectiveTimeStamp",
                     "c_Code":           "$level1.level2.c_code",
                     "f_Total":     "$level1.level2.level3.flevel_total",
                    }
                     }')
 )

  f_output = mongo.aggregation(db, coll_name, cmd_list)
```

When I use a large date range to filter records, I get the error "*Error in mongo.aggregation(db, coll_name, cmd_list) : 
  mongoDB error: 10. Please check ?mongo.get.err for more details.*
"

However, if I run the same program multiple times with smaller date ranges each time, the code runs successfully. I've tried increasing the session timeout time to a large value to check if that makes any difference but even that doesn't work. 
Any ideas what I'm doing incorrectly here? Appreciate any help that I can get to get this issue resolved.

Comment: Have you the query in the the mongo shell to see if it works?

Comment: Have you tried calling [mongo.get.err()](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmongodb/versions/1.5.3/topics/mongo.get.err) to get more details of what the error was?